# Need to refactor field names in eclipse which should change getters/setters as well

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to do lot of refactoring (actually need to change field names) in eclipse. It is changing all occurrences, references of fields.  But one thing is it is not changing getter/setter names which have been generated based on previous name.

Do we have any plugin to do this or any configuration change needed to be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, in Galileo the "rename" dialog has an option for changing the setters and getters of a field - [see here](http://satukubik.com/2009/08/07/eclipse-tips-renaming-field-and-its-settergetter/). (Alternatively, you can use `ALT + SHIFT + R` twice after selecting the field)

Before Galileo, you'd have to do 3 actions instead of one (not that bad)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bozho :) It is a lot better for me now.
Though there is a small problem still, it is not considering setter's parameter name.

Comment: hm, yes, that's a fair point. You can leave it, or you can manually change it.

Comment: You can also press ALT + SHIFT + R twice to open the rename dialog

Comment: Link is dead, see http://web.archive.org/web/20100513020351/http://satukubik.com/2009/08/07/eclipse-tips-renaming-field-and-its-settergetter/

Answer (score 2):

ALT+SHIFT+R is the default keyboard shortcut for renaming ... it's awesome!

Comment: it in fact *does* give you a dialog with options for renaming the getter and setter methods.

Comment: Hi LES2, yes.. that is the keyboard shortcut but in Galileo you have to press it two times to get the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real necessity for 'getters' and 'setters' to have the same name as the internal field. In fact many would argue that linking the two together is a violation of the data hiding principles of object oriented programming. Part of the point of having getters and setters is to protect the rest of the code from changes that are internal to the class, like renaming.

Having said that, if you absolutely decide that you need to rename the methods as well as the fields, then Eclipse will do it for you. You have to do them separately, but the same 'rename' that you are using for renaming fields works for methods. Just select the method and do what you did before.

Comment: Thanks DJClayworth.  But, how a private variable having same name as its getters/setters would violate data hiding principles?
Since it is private, no body would be able to access it directly..right?

Comment: You are right. But if you FORCED a change of the getters and setters when you changed the variable name, that would violate data hiding, because a change to the internal structure of the class would force a change to the classes interacting with it.

You might want to think about what you would do if you restructured the class so the internal data was stored in a different format, so the field no longer existed. Good design says you need to keep the getters and setters: what do you call them then?

Comment: Understood now

In my case it is new code and I have had to just change the name 2, 3 times before committing it.

Though it would be violating OOPS principles, I think, if I can change all the calls to getters/setters as well (since all calls happening from the code under my control) Shouldn't we be changing them to keep code more readable?

Comment: Yes I agree you should, provided the codebase is still small enough to fit in a single Eclipse project (so that automatic rename can do the job) and that no code outside that Eclipse project is using the methods.

Answer (score 0):

> **Step-1** Go to Package Explorer
>
> **Step-2** Move to the field name which is to be renamed

[image]

> **Step-3** Press F2. A rename dialog box will appear
>
> **Step-4** Tick mark checkboxes to rename getter and setter too. Click OK.

[image]

**You're done.**